# Show last 5 purchase order products details in shopping cart page (like last minuts shopping)

Tags: magento-1.9, product, sales

I am using SQL commend but its not working. Then how to show last 5 purchase order products detail in over shopping cart page.

```
  $store_id = 1;

    $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('product_id')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
                ->addAttributeToSort('main_table.created_at', 'DESC');
    $collection->getSelect()->join( array('so' => 'sales_flat_order'), 'main_table.order_id = so.entity_id AND so.store_id=' . $store_id, array(''));
    $collection->getSelect()->limit(5);
```

Please help me.

Comment: Are you want last five ordered product ids or  last live orders product list

Comment: customer purchases last five order details

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        $customer_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
        $orderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customer_id)->addOrder('created_at','desc');
        $orderModel->getSelect()->limit(5);
        $products_ids = array();
        foreach($orderModel as $order){
            foreach($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item):
                $products_ids[] = $item->getProductId();
            endforeach;
        }

        $uniqueProductsIds = array_unique($products_ids);

        $productsCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                                ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','description','price','url_key')) // add whatever product attributes you want
                                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('in' => $uniqueProductsIds));

        foreach ($productsCollection as $product) {
            echo $product->getName();
            echo $product->getDescription();
            echo $product->getUrlKey();
            echo $product->getPrice();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: This command not working my copan.phtml file please tell me path when i execute this query.

Comment: have you replaced $customer_id with the actual customer id ?

Comment: i had tested code it is working

Comment: Pardeep please help me how to find-out customer id in my website

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: how to show product layout.Because using echo its not working.

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: Pardeep can't able to show product layout in my shopping cart page. I am run this code output will be black, nothing to show.. How i can used "echo" to layout this last purchases 5 products.Because i need to display name, description, url link and price.

Comment: now check my answer

Comment: Sorry pardeep but product not showing my shopping cart page . just i see black .

Comment: your code please

Comment: same code when you provide me.

Comment: debug yourself what is the issue.but my code is working code

Comment: Hello pradeep, sale/order database i have not column for product id, product name , description, url-key and etc. What i want. But some other database table i found out this think. Please tell me how i can use this table in my code because i don't know which modules used this table.Please help me find out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want **last five order ids** which ordered then **your code almost right**.

And your query give you **product ids not product objects**.

Need to add **`addAttributeToFilter('parent_id',array('null'=>true))`**

```
// getting last five order ids
$lastFiveOrder  =  Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
            ->getCollection()->addAttributetoSort('created_id','DESC')
                    ->setPageSize(5);

$lastFiveOrderids  =  $lastFiveOrder->getColumnValues('entity_id);


// getting those 5 orders product ids
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('product_id')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
                ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id',array('null'=>true));
        ->addAttributeToFilter('order_id',array('in'=>$lastFiveOrderids ));

$collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.product_id'); // make product id unique

// $productids give product ids in array
$productids = $collection->getColumnValues('product_id');

// get product object of those 5 orders
$productCollection =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addIdFilter($productids)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Comment: code not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply sort by `order_id`

```
$order_items = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');


 $order_items->getSelect()->order('order_id DESC');    
$order_items->getSelect()->limit(5);

foreach ($order_items as $order_item) {
    echo $order_item->getItemId();
}
```